# Matplotlib - Draw H and V line by specifying X or Y value on a plot

Tags: matplotlib, draw

I was wondering today about how finding a specific value on a plot and drawing the right line that goes with. I used to do that on an old chart library, and I was wondering that perhaps this functionnality exist but I don't know how to find it.
The result should look like this: https://miro.medium.com/max/1070/1*Ckhi9soE9Lx2lIf9tPVLMQ.png

To provide some context, I'm doing a PCA over my data, and I would like to point out some thresholds at 97.5, 99 and 99.5% of explained cumuled variance.

Have a great day!

EDIT:
See Answer

Comment: `plt.plot([0,x,x], [y,y,0])`?

Comment: I'm so dumb... Thanks you ImportanceOfBeingErnest !

Comment: Can you put your answer as an answer? I should then tag the topic as solved.

Comment: You just answered it yourself; just put it in an answer instead of the question (What would be the question then?)

Answer (score 0):

As solved by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, here is the code:

```
whole_pca = PCA().fit(np.array(inputs['Scale'].tolist()))
cumul = np.cumsum(np.round(whole_pca.explained_variance_ratio_, decimals=3)*100)
over_95 = np.argmax(cumul>95)
over_99 = np.argmax(cumul>99)
over_995 = np.argmax(cumul>99.5)
plt.plot(cumul)
plt.plot([0,over_95,over_95], [95,95,0])
plt.plot([0,over_99,over_99], [99,99,0])
plt.plot([0,over_995,over_995], [99.5,99.5,0])
plt.xlim(left=0)
plt.ylim(bottom=80)
plt.ylabel('% Variance Explained')
plt.xlabel('# of Features')
plt.title('PCA Analysis')
```

Result in:
[image]
Thank you!